# Scraping live-sports data without driver.refresh()?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

my goal is to scrape live data off a website as it changes. 
Here is an example URL:
http://www.liveticker.com/spiel/6HXLRTtd/#spiel-statistiken;0

I use python, selenium and time for the loop. While I kinda get what I want with Firefox I wanted to use PhantomJS (to not have several browser windows opening) but it stops scraping after 1-4 refreshes.

My guess as to why this happens: If you manually visit the page an hit refresh a few times you get a screen message telling you refreshing is not necessary. But that is only a guess, as Firefox still seems able to scrape the data.

So I wonder why PhantomJS stops scraping and what to do about it. Is there a method with python to continuously scrape live-data (AJAX I guess) without having to refresh or reload the page?

Hope you can help, I am pretty new to all this and did not find any relevant cues so far.

Here is my function just in case:

```
def get_games_stats(url): 
  driver.get(url)
  t=2
  starttime=time.time()
  t=float(t)

  while True:
    time.sleep(t - ((time.time() - starttime) % t))
    driver.refresh()        
    time.sleep(5)

    tabelle = driver.find_element_by_id("tab-statistics-0-statistic")
    text_tabelle = tabelle.text
    x = text_tabelle.encode( "utf-8" )
    x= [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', x)]

    team_a =  x[::2]
    team_b = x[1::2]
    print team_a, team_b
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've mentioned, sometimes after page refresh alert might appears. This might block your code execution. Try to handle this alert as below:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException

while True:
    time.sleep(t - ((time.time() - starttime) % t))
    driver.refresh()        
    time.sleep(5)

    # This might not work with PhantomJS
    #try:
    #    driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
    #except NoAlertPresentException:
    #    pass

    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }")
    except:
        pass

    tabelle = driver.find_element_by_id("tab-statistics-0-statistic")
    text_tabelle = tabelle.text
    x = text_tabelle.encode( "utf-8" )
    x= [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', x)]

    team_a =  x[::2]
    team_b = x[1::2]
    print team_a, team_b
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! This threw me an error: WebDriverException: Message: Invalid Command Method and referred after the function call to line `driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks again.